# Jenkins and Deployment

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Started with **Jenkins** recently,,

I got few questions about the same..

I know Jenkins can be used for Creating a build , Running Tests but Can we use Jenkins   for Deployment (i know its *Yes*).

my question is,
for Deploying a build there are some changes to be made into Properties file every   time   we deploy a build, so how this can be achieved using Jenkins ? Is that Possible ?

How my Selenium Testcases can be integrated with JENKINS ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't achieve that with Jenkins. You achieve that with your deployment script (which is triggered by Jenkins).

Comment: yes.. correct. Once the .war is generated, i need to stop the Server, Place the .war file in specified path and Restart the Server. Can this be done using Jenkins ?

Comment: Once again, Jenkins just executes what you tell it to execute. In majority of cases, it is _your_ responsibility to **write** the deployment script (bash, batch, python, etc). For simple .war file in particular, there is a [Deploy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) plugin available. You can find similar plugins for other artifacts. But for any custom functionality, you have to write your own deployment scripts. In your case, the change to the properties file is a custom functionality, and will require your own deployment script to be written.

Comment: Cool. So its all about Shell scripting or Windows batch commands to do all the Work i mentioned above. Am i right

Comment: @METIsatish for specific cases, such as changing properties in your case, yes. If it was a simple "take file and put there", then there are plugins for that, such as the `Deploy` plugin I already mentioned.

Comment: Thanksss... The .war file is generating and Placing of the .war file will be achieved soon. How i can run my Selenium Webdriver TestCases once the Build is Deployed ?? Is there any Post Build Plugin ??

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins executes tasks, so if you want to deploy automaticly your webapp for example, you should make a script that copies the war to the webapp directory / server.

I personnaly use jenkins for deployement on my integration server.
I do not use jenkins for production.

Concerning Selenium, it can be acheived with selenium server standalone with headless.

It is really a pain in the *** to make it work but I managed to do it using :
* xvnc (for headless)
* a call to selenium server using shell script (the plugin does not work for me)

My script command for jenkins looks something like :

```
vncserver :6
export DISPLAY=:6


java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -acceptSslCerts -ensureCleanSession -htmlSuite "*chrome" "$URLStart" "$suiteTestFile" "$resultTestFile" -port 7856


vncserver -kill :6
```

Where $suiteTestFile is your HtmlSuite
and *resultTestFile is your outputhtml

Then, for reporting purpuse, use jenkins htmlreport plugin.

Moreover, you do not have to stop your tomcat server to deploy your webapp, tomcat manages to deploy automaticly all WAR files.

Comment: For me, running selenium headless with firefox is not working.

I use EC2 / Ubuntu 14

Comment: That's cool.. My Jenkins server is running in Linux machine and My Selenium scripts are in Windows. Can u tell me how to Start Selenium Execution using **testng.xml** ??? Can i access my windows drive through Jenkins installed on Linux ??